# How to pass parameter from parent for to the child for (for in for) in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Trying to pass a parameter incremented by parent for to child for processing, but can't figure why is not working. Tried lots of variations of this code:

```
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    echo Processing %%a
    set folder=%cd%\%%a
    echo test folder is %folder%
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo test folder is !folder!
    for /R !folder! %%i in (*.log) do (
        find /i "error" %%i
        )
    endlocal
    )
```

Removed the commenting that wasn't in the original code, believed it would help, it didn't. Sorry! Anyway problem is !folder! in 2nd for statement is not being resolved (or resolved as !folder!)

What i need to do is start from a root folder named results where there are lots of other folders that contain other folders witch contain log files. I have to process all primary folders d:\results\test1 test2 .. testn and in every folder i have to generate a report where put files with errors files with size=0 etc + more.

structure looks like

```
result
    test1
        phase1
            log files
        phase2
            log files
        .
        .
        phasen
    test2
    .
    .
    testn
```

Comment: Edit your question and discuss the problem - providing broken code doesn't help when the actual task isn't known.

Comment: This line will kill the loop `::other processing` because `::` before parenthesis causes the loop to fail.  Use `REM` inside a loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /D %%a in (*) do (
  echo Processing %%a
  set folder="%cd%\%%a"
  call:testlog !folder!
)
exit/b

:testlog
echo test folder is %1
for /R %1 %%i in (*.log) do find /i "error" "%%i"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should place your `setlocal` declaration outside the loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample doesn't need `delayed expansion`

```
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    echo Processing %%a
    echo test folder is "%cd%\%%a"
    for /R "%cd%\%%a" %%i in (*.log) do (
        find /i "error" "%%i"
        )
    )
```